# Second Cursor is not triggering a screen refresh

Tags: ubuntu, xlib, multiple-monitors, xorg, xinput

I previously posted about controlling two separate cursors in two xsessions. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714831/controlling-multiple-pointers-with-xlib-or-xinput-in-ubuntu-linux)

That solution worked well. However, a odd thing occurs when I control the cursor. Instead of the cursor moving normally and the screen refreshing to adjust, the cursor is on top of a white box and when I move it the cursor leaves a trail and nothing refreshes. This only happens when I move the newly created cursor in the second screen. Best I can guess is that when I move the cursor the xsession isn't getting any event notice or something and it never refreshes though I have no idea if that's the issue. I'm sorry I'm a bit vague I'm just having trouble describing the issue. It's like in the old days when the screen would freeze and you would drag the window and it would leave a trail. That's exactly what's happening with the cursor.

Might it have something to do with the fact that it's not in the xorg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the reason that this was happening is that I was using gdm. Gdm doesn't have very good support for multiseating systems (multiple users/single computer). Initially, after the above failed, I tried configuring the xorg.conf to create multiple layout each with it's own input devices. This failed, again because of gdm. Once I switch to kdm I was able to set the xorg.conf so that each monitor started with it's own keyboard/mouse set.