# Linux: Xautomation with fake mouse pointer

Tags: linux, mouse, xinput

I have created a fake mouse pointer using the `xinput` command as outlined [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/MPX) which produces a second pointer that hovers in the center of my screen.

I would now like to automate it using the `xte` command, but unfortunately `xte` only seems grab control of the hardware mouse that I wish to keep free.

The man page for `xte` does not have any flags to specify which pointer to take control of. 
I was wondering if anybody had any ideas?

NB: The second pointer is purely for me to able to work on the same computer whilst running the graphical pipeline

---

Edit: So by looking at the xte source I've found references to XQueryPointer

```
Bool XQueryPointer(display, w, root_return, child_return, root_x_return, root_y_return, 
                     win_x_return, win_y_return, mask_return)
      Display *display;
      Window w;
      Window *root_return, *child_return;
      int *root_x_return, *root_y_return;
      int *win_x_return, *win_y_return;
      unsigned int *mask_return;

//Arguments:
display         Specifies the connection to the X server.
w               Specifies the window.
root_return     Returns the root window that the pointer is in.
child_return    Returns the child window that the pointer is located in, if any.
root_x_return
root_y_return   Return the pointer coordinates relative to the root window's origin.
win_x_return
win_y_return    Return the pointer coordinates relative to the specified window.
mask_return     Returns the current state of the modifier keys and pointer buttons.
```

from the Xlib class, which as you can see returns only the first mouse pointer and does not give option for another.

---

Edit2: Looking through the libx11-dev source I'm finding mentions of it at ./src/QuPntr.c and Xlibint.h, but the code is getting harder to read and I'm out of my depth here

Answer (score 0):

`xinput` makes use of the XI2 extension to allow for multiple pointers.
This library (`X11/extensions/XInput2.h`) provides functions prefixed by "XI" which accept a device parameter (the same referenced by `xinput --list`), for instance XIQueryPointer, XIWarpPointer or XIGetClientPointer.
Thus you can control your fake pointer programmatically if your automation tool doesn’t support XI2.

In a simpler way, it could suffice to `xinput --reattach` the hardware device (a slave device) to the new pointer (a master device).

Very late answer I know, but I came across this question via web search so I add what I know for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there isn't any mention of XQueryPointer inside the source code of xte.c (there are only a few inside xmousepos.c, which is code for a different tool).
I checked a few older versions that existed before you asked the question.

The relevant functions are XIWarpPointer and XTestFakeDeviceButtonEvent. As seen here in the reduced source code:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XInput2.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XTest.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int delta_x = 500, delta_y = 160;
  Display *display = XOpenDisplay(0);
  Window root = DefaultRootWindow(display);
  XIWarpPointer(display, 14, None, root, 0, 0, 0, 0, delta_x, delta_y);
  XDevice *device = NULL;
  device = XOpenDevice(display, 16);
  XTestFakeDeviceButtonEvent(display, device, 1, True, 0, 0, CurrentTime);
  XTestFakeDeviceButtonEvent(display, device, 1, False, 0, 0, CurrentTime);
  XCloseDisplay(display);
}
```

which does the same thing as **xte -i 16 "mousemove 500 160" "mouseclick 1"**.

But what might bother you (at least it bothers me): Windows that got clicked gain focus, effectively unfocusing the window that you were working on.
Actually I asked a question that asks for an alternative to XTestFakeDeviceButtonEvent just recently ([Sending a button press event for a second pointing device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59597037/sending-a-button-press-event-for-a-second-pointing-device); I also provided some example code that actually performs mouse clicks without giving focus to a window, so it's possible but dunno how it's done with another pointing device)..
An alternative might be to work with multiple X sessions like this user did it: [Controlling multiple pointers with Xlib or xinput in ubuntu/linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714831/controlling-multiple-pointers-with-xlib-or-xinput-in-ubuntu-linux?rq=1). Sadly he hasn't shared any code.
I have some hope with uinput (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/input/uinput.html) but haven't tried it yet.